# AVR Microbasic TFT ILI9325 LCD Proteus simulation

Tags: basic, lcd

If anyone worked with Nokia N96 LCD Display with ILI9325 Display controller, please let me knew.

I am writing Basic code that helps display a character on the screen. The screen is 320 by 240 pixel matrix. The controller provides a GRAM(Graphics RAM) memory where in we write the data to display corresponding character.

I Found the Proteus library for TFT ILI9325 form this link:
[dll file of ILI9325 GLCD for proteus](https://www.4shared.com/rar/ysvJltAVei/ILI9325.html)
and 
[Proteus simulation on bascom](http://fm.elasa.ir/showthread.php?130-%D8%B4%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%87-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%AF%DB%8C-ILI9325-Nokia-N96-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-Proteus)

And so when i want to change it to mirobasic software with below code,LCD don't show anything!!!

The Microbasic Codes based of ILI9325 datasheet:

```
program MyProject

'*******************************************************************************
'----- Color LCD CONFIG --------------------------------------------------------
'*******************************************************************************


dim Back_light as sbit at Portg0_bit
dim Color_lcd_cs as sbit at Porta3_bit
dim Color_lcd_rs as sbit at PORTa0_bit
dim Color_lcd_wr as sbit at PORTa1_bit
dim Color_lcd_rd as sbit at PORTa2_bit
dim Color_lcd_rst as sbit at PORTa4_bit


dim Color_lcd_lsb_port as byte at PORTD ' this is where PORTAlias is fully defined
dim Color_lcd_msb_port as byte at PORTE ' this is where PORTAlias is fully defined


Dim Entry_mod As Word                                       'Horizantal=&H1028,Vertical=&H1030
Dim Color_lcd_index As Byte                                 'Index Variable
Dim Color_lcd_data As Word                                  'Data Variable
Dim Lcd_buff As String [ 25]
Dim xX As Word
Dim Yy As Word
Dim O As Word
Dim X_c As Word
Dim Y_c As Word





'*******************************************************************************
'*******************************************************************************
'----- COLOR LCD SUBROUTINES ---------------------------------------------------
'*******************************************************************************
'*******************************************************************************
Sub procedure Triger_color_lcd()
Color_lcd_rst=0
delay_ms( 60)
Color_lcd_rst=1
delay_ms( 200)Color_lcd_index = 0xE3 '' Write_color_lcd_index
Color_lcd_data = 0x3008 '' Write_color_lcd_data
Color_lcd_index = 0x00E7 '' Write_color_lcd_index
Color_lcd_data = 0x0000 '' Write_color_lcd_data
End Sub


Sub procedure Write_color_lcd_index()
Color_lcd_cs=0
Color_lcd_rs=0
Color_lcd_rd=1
Color_lcd_msb_port = 0x00
Color_lcd_lsb_port = Color_lcd_index
 Color_lcd_wr=0
 Color_lcd_wr=1
 Color_lcd_cs=1
End Sub

Sub procedure Write_color_lcd_data()
Color_lcd_cs=0
Color_lcd_rs=1
Color_lcd_rd=1
Color_lcd_msb_port = Hi(color_lcd_data)
Color_lcd_lsb_port =  Lo(color_lcd_data)
Color_lcd_wr=
Color_lcd_wr=1
Color_lcd_cs=1
end sub


'*******************************************************************************

main:


Color_lcd_index = 0x13 '' Write_color_lcd_index
Color_lcd_data = 0x1111 '' Write_color_lcd_data

 Write_color_lcd_index()
 Write_color_lcd_data()
while True


 wend
'   Main program
end.
```

the code with Proteus is [Here]:

***www.filepi.com/i/1pnpxUD***

and the result is the same as this picture:

***www.i.stack.imgur.com/7xsR2.jpg***

Answer (score 0):

No answer!!!
So i found the proper answer and proper codes  with MikroC for AVR here:

main.c:

```
    //================================ LCD CONFIGURATIONS =======================================
 #define PORTRAIT

 #define LCD_CONTROLPORT_DDR  DDRA
 #define LCD_CONTROLPORT_PORT PORTA
 #define LCD_CONTROLPORT_PIN  PINA

 #define LCD_RST_DDR  DDRA
 #define LCD_RST_PORT PORTA
 #define LCD_RST_PIN  4

 #define LCD_RS_DDR  DDRA
 #define LCD_RS_PORT PORTA
 #define LCD_RS_PIN  0

 #define LCD_CS_DDR  DDRA
 #define LCD_CS_PORT PORTA
 #define LCD_CS_PIN  3

 #define LCD_RD_DDR  DDRA
 #define LCD_RD_PORT PORTA
 #define LCD_RD_PIN  2

 #define LCD_WR_DDR  DDRA
 #define LCD_WR_PORT PORTA
 #define LCD_WR_PIN  1

 #define LCD_DATAPORT_MSB_DDR   DDRE
 #define LCD_DATAPORT_MSB_PORT  PORTE
 #define LCD_DATAPORT_MSB_PIN   PINE

 #define LCD_DATAPORT_LSB_DDR   DDRD
 #define LCD_DATAPORT_LSB_PORT  PORTD
 #define LCD_DATAPORT_LSB_PIN   PIND



 //================================================================

#include "tftlcd_functions.h"

void main(void)
{
 lcd_init();
// lcd_background_color(GREEN);
while (1)
      {

      lcd_gotoxy(11,11);
      lcd_putsf(" TFT LCD 2.8' ",0x0000,0,RED);
      lcd_gotoxy(11,11);
      lcd_putsf(" www.Elasa.ir ",0x0000,0,BLUE);
      Delay_ms(200);
      lcd_clear_screen();
      lcd_background_color(BLACK);
      lcd_draw_line(5,5,50,50,0xFFFF);
      lcd_draw_rectangle(30,30,80,80,0,0XFFFF);
      lcd_draw_circle(150,150,25,0,0xffff);
      Delay_ms(200);
      }
}
```

[Proteus Simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvPRP.jpg)

and the other files with Proteus simulation in this file:

http://filepi.com/i/VlZM9PN

[Files for Download](http://fm.elasa.ir/showthread.php?130-%D8%B4%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%87-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%AF%DB%8C-ILI9325-Nokia-N96-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-Proteus)

sincerely yours:
 Soheil sabz